# LDAP BIND invalid DN

Tags: ldap

I want to use Ldap_bind here's my code :

```
 $ldap_host = '192.168.1.250'; //Host LDAP
 $ldap_user = "cn=admin,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com";
 $ldap_pass = 'admin';
 $ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_host);
 ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

 if($ldap_conn) 
 {
  if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $ldap_user, $ldap_pass)){

  }
  else
  {
    die('Koneksi ke LDAP Gagal');
  }
 }
```

Everything good when i execute that code. But when i change the $ldap_user with admin@maxcrc.com .There's error apear said

> "Unable to bind to server: Invalid DN syntax"

Whats wrong with that?How could i bind with domain. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's because ldap_bind() is expecting a DN - a distinguished name, which is like the full path to the object. You can't use the user@domain syntax when binding this way.

You can sometimes use the RDN also - the relative DN - (so simply 'username'), but usually the directory expects the full DN.

Comment: i just read article that use the user@domain here's the article

http://samjlevy.com/2010/09/php-login-script-using-ldap-verify-group-membership/

Comment: I guess Active Directory accepts that format as well, but that's not standard LDAP behavior from what I can tell. Are you using AD?

Comment: if i do not use AD? what kind of data that i have build in phpldapadmin? I really confuse bout LDAP and AD..

Comment: AD is Microsoft's implementation of LDAP with added features. LDAP is just a protocol for interfacing with a directory. phpldapadmin should be able to tell you what you're using if you don't know.